# Javafx: No toolkit found exception

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-webengine, jfxpanel

I have added the javafx library in my intellij plugin for adding the jfxwebview.

But when I am trying to create JFXPanel object as

JFXPanle jfxpanel = new JFXPanel();

It is giving the following exception:

```
No toolkit found
java.lang.RuntimeException: No toolkit found
at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit(Toolkit.java:217)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:209)
at javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel.initFx(JFXPanel.java:215)
at javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel.<init>(JFXPanel.java:230)
at com.example.test.CustomPanel.<init>(CustomPanel.java:21)
at com.example.test.TestFileEditor.<init>(TestFileEditor.java:25)
at com.example.test.TestFileEditorProvider.createEditor(TestFileEditorProvider.java:27)
at com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.impl.FileEditorManagerImpl$14.run(FileEditorManagerImpl.java:894)
at com.intellij.util.ui.UIUtil.invokeAndWaitIfNeeded(UIUtil.java:2461)
at com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.impl.FileEditorManagerImpl.openFileImpl4(FileEditorManagerImpl.java:876)
at com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.impl.FileEditorManagerImpl.openFileImpl3(FileEditorManagerImpl.java:810)
at com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.impl.FileEditorManagerImpl$11.run(FileEditorManagerImpl.java:790)
at com.intellij.openapi.command.impl.CoreCommandProcessor.executeCommand(CoreCommandProcessor.java:117)
at com.intellij.openapi.command.impl.CoreCommandProcessor.executeCommand(CoreCommandProcessor.java:99)
at com.intellij.openapi.command.impl.CoreCommandProcessor.executeCommand(CoreCommandProcessor.java:85)
at com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.impl.FileEditorManagerImpl.openFileImpl2(FileEditorManagerImpl.java:787)
at com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.impl.FileEditorManagerImpl.openFileWithProviders(FileEditorManagerImpl.java:728)
at com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.ex.FileEditorManagerEx.openFile(FileEditorManagerEx.java:151)
at com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.impl.FileEditorManagerImpl$17.run(FileEditorManagerImpl.java:1156)
at com.intellij.openapi.command.impl.CoreCommandProcessor.executeCommand(CoreCommandProcessor.java:124)
at com.intellij.openapi.command.impl.CoreCommandProcessor.executeCommand(CoreCommandProcessor.java:99)
at com.intellij.openapi.command.impl.CoreCommandProcessor.executeCommand(CoreCommandProcessor.java:85)
at com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.impl.FileEditorManagerImpl.openEditor(FileEditorManagerImpl.java:1152)
at com.intellij.ide.util.EditorHelper.openInEditor(EditorHelper.java:66)
at com.intellij.ide.projectView.impl.ProjectViewImpl$MyIdeView.selectElement(ProjectViewImpl.java:1261)
at com.intellij.ide.actions.CreateElementActionBase.actionPerformed(CreateElementActionBase.java:78)
at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.performActionDumbAware(ActionUtil.java:191)
at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem$ActionTransmitter$1.run(ActionMenuItem.java:312)
at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FocusManagerImpl.runOnOwnContext(FocusManagerImpl.java:958)
at
com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.IdeFocusManagerImpl.runOnOwnContext(IdeFocusManagerImpl.java:124)
 at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem$ActionTransmitter.actionPerformed(ActionMenuItem.java:282)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem.fireActionPerformed(ActionMenuItem.java:110)
at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI.doClick(BegMenuItemUI.java:513)
at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI.access$300(BegMenuItemUI.java:45)
at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI$MyMouseInputHandler.mouseReleased(BegMenuItemUI.java:533)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:857)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:654)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:386)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You have to install jfx. If you are using ubuntu, the command is:

```
sudo apt-get install openjfx libopenjfx-java
```

Comment: it's work for me with java 1.8.0.181 on ubuntu 18.04. tnx